# How to get a session from async_session() generator FastApi Sqlalchemy

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlalchemy, python-asyncio, fastapi

I see in many places an approach for getting SqlAlchemy session just like this one below:

```py
async def get_session() -> AsyncSession:
    async with async_session() as session:
        yield session
```

It used together with Depends:

```
@app.post("/endpoint")
async def vieww(session: AsyncSession = Depends(get_session)):
    session.execute(some_statement)
```

**So my question is how to get a session from `get_session` ooutside Depends?**

I had a lot of attempts and got a headache..
I tried with

```
s = await get_session()
s.execute(stmt)
```

And I get `AttributeError: 'async_generator' object has no attribute 'execute'`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`get_session` is an [asynchronous generator function](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-asynchronous-generator). It returns an [asynchronous iterator](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#asynchronous-iterators). You can't `await` those. You *can* await their [`__anext__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__anext__) method though.

```py
from asyncio import run
from collections.abc import AsyncIterator


async def get_generator() -> AsyncIterator[int]:
    yield 1


async def main() -> None:
    generator = get_generator()
    print(await generator.__anext__())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    run(main())
```

Output: `1`

Since Python `3.10` we can use the built-in [`anext`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#anext), which makes this look less hacky:

```py
...
async def main() -> None:
    generator = get_generator()
    print(await anext(generator)
...
```

So in your case, you could use `s = await anext(get_session())`.

But I struggle to see the use of this. This `get_session` function is designed as an asynchronous generator for the *specific* use case in the FastAPI [`Depends`](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/dependencies/dependencies-with-yield/) construct. Outside of that, you may as well just use the context manager normally:

```py
async with async_session() as session:
    ... # do things with the session
    session.execute()
```

Otherwise you'll have to remember to call `__anext__` on that generator **again** (and catch the [`StopAsyncIteration`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#StopAsyncIteration) error), otherwise the session will never be closed.

Answer (score 1):

Check this [article](https://www.ricdelgado.com/articles/17-building-fastapi-strawberry-nextjs-rsc-pt3). Basically you can pass the session via context:

First crete the AsyncSession

```
async def get_session() -> AsyncSession:
    async_session = sessionmaker(engine, class_=AsyncSession, expire_on_commit=False)
    async with async_session() as session:
        yield session
```

Create the context. This is the key part, in here you can use the Dependency.

```
async def get_context(session: AsyncSession = Depends(get_session)):
    return {'session': session}
```

Add it into the context_gettr param

```
graphql_app = GraphQLRouter(schema, context_getter=get_context)
```

And now it is usable from everywhere like this:

```
@strawberry.type
class Query:
    @strawberry.field
    async def songs(self, info: Info) -> typing.List[SongType]:
        """ Get all songs """
        session = info.context['session']
        songs_data_list = await get_songs(session)
        return songs_data_list

async def get_songs(session) -> typing.List[SongType]:
    """ Get all songs resolver """
    result = await session.exec(select(Song))
    ... # now you have the query result, do whatever you want from here
```